# Rename one file during copying process with Gulp

Tags: gulp, gulp-rename

I want to automate the process of packing my extension for Chrome and Firefox and for that I'm using Gulp. I have two different manifest files, one for Chrome and one for Firefox (`manifest.json` and `manifestff.json`) in the root directory of the project. Now, I want to:

1. Copy everything needed to directory for Chrome extension.
2. Do the same thing for Firefox extension except that I want to rename `manifestff.json` into `manifest.json` in the process.

Here is my current task for packing extension for Firefox:

```
gulp.task('pack-firefox', () => {
    return gulp.src([
        'manifestff.json',
        'index.html',
        './public/**'
    ], {'base': '.'})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./ff'));
}
```

Is it possible to specify (with additional `.pipe()`) that I want to copy `manifestff.json` as `manifest.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [gulp-if](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-if)

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const gulpIF = require('gulp-if');


gulp.task('pack-firefox', () => {
  return gulp.src([
    'manifestff.json',
    'index.html',
    './public/**'
  ], { 'base': '.' })
    .pipe(gulpIF(function (file) { return file.path.match('manifestff.json') }, rename('manifest.json')))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./ff'));
});
```